# How to remove comments from an XML file?

Tags: command-line, xml

Is there a command line tool that can remove comments from an XML file? Or do I need to write a small program that makes use of an XML parser to do this?

**Update**: I'm not interested in solutions that only handle a subset of all possible XML files.

For instance a regexp can't handle XML parsing.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la

Answer (score 18):

I would do it in this way:

```
cat myfile.xml | sed '/<!--.*-->/d' | sed '/<!--/,/-->/d' > cleaned.xml
```

Or:

```
awk 'in_comment&&/-->/{sub(/([^-]|-[^-])*--+>/,"");in_comment=0}
 in_comment{next}
 {gsub(/<!--+([^-]|-[^-])*--+>/,"");
  in_comment=sub(/<!--+.*/,"");
  print}'
```

Or:

```
xmlstarlet ed -d '//comment()' file.xml
```

Comment: I know regex solutions can't handle XML parsing (without possible errors). But I guess the third solution is using a real XML parser under the hood?

Comment: Erik, yes, xmlstarlet is designed for xml manipulation.

Comment: Ok, I checked. xmlstarlet uses libxml2. If you remove the first *sed* and *awk* suggestions that are not correct according to me,  I'll accept the *xmlstarlet* suggestion as the accepted answer.

Comment: it's disappointing to know that none of the big editors (Sublime, vim, Atom, Notepad++) have this feature built-in. Sad, sad, sad. Thanks @Frantique

Comment: I would like to keep only comments that contain "TODO" on it, any idea if possible with xmlstarlet?

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the top answer. If you only want to delete the comment and not the entire line, you should probably use:

```
sed 's/<!--.*-->//'
```

In my case, I had a minified XML file where the entire content was in a single line and since the previous solution would delete the entire line where the comment was located, it would completely clear out my file.

Comment: Quote from the question "_I'm not interested in solutions that only handle a subset of all possible XML files._". The difficult thing is finding a solution that can handle all XML files, not just a subset.

Answer (score 0):

This is good to clean multiline comments (like failed tests) from a xml, least the ones you hand picked and are helpful to the end user:
`perl -i -w -0777pe 's/<!--(.(?<!(HELP|TODO)))*?-->//sg' somefile.xml`

more about related regex: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1240293/1422630

If there is a way to obtain the same result but using xmlstarlet, I would prefer as there may have some exception that regex may not handle, but for now this is what I have to use.

Comment: This solution only handle a subset of all possible XML files is therefore not relevant to the question asked. (Regex solutions only handle a subset of all possible XML files) See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la

Comment: I will ask a new question thx!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73200053/how-to-remove-all-comments-from-a-xml-file-least-the-ones-containing-the-help